# Adding a CLI for PHP5 on live server

Tags: php, nginx, command-line-interface, php5

I want to add command-line support for PHP5 on my server. When I run `aptitude install php5-cli` I get a message saying that my PHP modules/packages have unmet dependencies.

Here is a list of packages that suffer from these "unmet dependencies" and needs and upgrade:

- php5-gd
- php5-curl
- php5-mysql
- php5-cgi

They all depend on php5-common.

Can I upgrade the packages just like aptitude suggests without causing any disruptions to the live site?

Output from aptitude

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initialising package states... Done
The following packages are BROKEN:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cgi php5-curl php5-gd php5-mysql 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-cli 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php5-common 
1 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 123 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,511kB of archives. After unpacking 7,803kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-gd: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid) but 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid is to be installed.
  php5-curl: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid) but 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid is to be installed.
  php5-mysql: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid) but 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid is to be installed.
  php5-cgi: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid) but 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid is to be installed.
  libapache2-mod-php5: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid) but 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Upgrade the following packages:
libapache2-mod-php5 [5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid (now) -> 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid (lucid)]
php5-cgi [5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid (now) -> 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid (lucid)]
php5-curl [5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid (now) -> 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid (lucid)]
php5-gd [5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid (now) -> 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid (lucid)]
php5-mysql [5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid (now) -> 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid (lucid)]

Score is 340
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is *maybe*! ;-)

PHP 5.3.3 to 5.3.5 shouldn't matter. That is, unless Ubuntu/Debian did something extra crazy. But point releases (e.g. 5.3.x to 5.3.y) should never break a feature set.

That is to say, that hopefully you didn't do crazy hacks and e.g. relied on bugs in 5.3.3 which were fixed in 5.3.5 and therefor would cause a regression. The easiest way to test this is to spin up a test VM and see if your site works (or even better: your test suite runs).

Another trick is to try to install 5.3.3 – here's an idea (note my version is different):

```
# apt-cache showpkg php5-cli
Package: php5-cli
Versions: 
5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.10
...
```

(I truncated the output.)

Then install with:

```
# apt-get install php5-cli=5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.10
...
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You're using Nginx PPA and Aptitude tries to update packages for newer versions. If you want to install php5-cli from Ubuntu repository you must use `aptitude install php5-cli=5.3.3-1ubuntu12~lucid`.